# thread access to variables in use

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I was wondering, if i have a multi-core processor and i have multiple threads,is it possible that the program will crash if 2 or more threads access a variable at the same time? How can i block temporarily a variable so that simultaneously access is restricted?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: In special case where variable is initialized before any thread starts, and threads only read the variable, then you don't need any synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is possible that the program will crash if 2 or more threads access a variable at the same time

It is unlikely that the program will crash. It probably won't behave as you expect it to as it will create a race condition.

> How can i block temporarily a variable so that multiple access simultaneously is restricted

Using a [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! But if i lock an object and some stream needs to write to that object, the stream will wait for the object to be unlocked and proceed as normal ? or will it try to access, see it can't access and skip this task ?

Comment: If another thread tries to lock on some object which is currently being locked this other thread will block and wait until the first thread releases the lock.

Comment: Ah you've enlightened me! Regards!

Answer (score 5):

It won't *crash*, but it might give the wrong results.

To block, you need to make sure that every access is protected via a lock statement on the same monitor:

```
private readonly object monitor = new object();
private int sharedVariable;

public void MethodThatSetsVariable()
{
    lock (monitor)
    {
        sharedVariable = 5;
    }
}

public void MethodThatReadsVariable()
{
    int foo;
    lock (monitor)
    {
        foo = sharedVariable;
    }
    // Use foo now
}
```

Alternatives:

- Use a `volatile` variable, although the exact behaviour of `volatile` is hard to understand. (Well, it's beyond me, anyway.)
- Use methods on the `Interlocked` class

Note that both of these are best suited when it's only a single shared variable you're interested in. When you've got to access a set of variables, making sure you only ever see a fully consistent state, locks are the easiest way to go.

Another option - and preferred if at all possible - is to avoid requiring mutable shared state in the first place. It's not always possible, at least without a complete redesign to a messaging-passing architecture - but it's worth aiming for where possible. Immutable types can help to make this easier to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `lock` keyword, or `Interlocked` class.

e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
   private object barLock = new object();
   private int bar;

   public void Add(int x)
   {
        lock (barLock)
        {
            this.bar += x;
        }
   }
}
```

or

```
public class Foo
{
   private int bar;

   public void Increment()
   {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
   }
}
```

I would use the `Interlocked` class whenever possible, as this is generally the simplest and most efficient (fastest) way to do this, but only certain operations are catered for. For more complex operations, a `lock` is the way to go.

I would recommend against using the C# `volatile` keyword as this affects *all* access to a given field. It's better stick to higher level concepts such as `lock` or `Interlocked`.

Answer (score 1):

using a [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement (which is really syntactic sugar for a Monitor.Enter/Exit)